# Is ./path necessary?

Tags: html, path

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

The above is what I see in index.php of phpMyAdmin.

Isn't it the same as:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Or say, can you give an example where these two generates different results?

Answer (score 1):

Same thing, no advantage of one over the other, just personal preference.

Comment: Not exactly true... There is an advantage of dropping the `./`: saving 2 bytes an x amount of times.

Answer (score 1):

The convention of using ./foo stems from when foo is an executable script and ./ is not in your default path. For just looking up files, as in your example, there is no difference.

Comment: But this does not concern relative URIs.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. In fact, the `./` will be removed anyways (see [RFC 3986 – 5.2.4.  Remove Dot Segments](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)):

> ```
>  2.  While the input buffer is not empty, loop as follows:
>
>      A.  If the input buffer begins with a prefix of "../" or "./",
>          then remove that prefix from the input buffer; otherwise,
>  …
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Those two paths are exactly the same. They are appended after the lastmost directory separator. So for http://example.com/site/index.html, the URL will become either http://example.com/site/./favicon.ico or http://example.com/site/favicon.ico. But when those URL's are normalized, both will result in http://example.com/site/favicon.ico because any /./ in a path will be replaced with / when normalizing.

In general I would use the second version.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of choice, as i like

```
<img src="./dir/myimage.jpg" />
```

over

```
<img src="dir/myimage.jpg" />
```